# hive - column level subquery workaround

Tags: hive, hiveql

i've stumbled in column level subquery, lets say i want a result like this:

[image]

from self join table contain (date, store and transaction)

i know it's achieveable using traditional data warehouse (using column level subquery) but i discover that hive is lacking this feature, so i create my own query like this:

```
select main_table.date,main_table.store,main_table.transaction,yest_table.transaction as yesterday_trans, lw_table.transaction as lastweek_trans, lm_table.transaction as lastmonth_trans
    from
    (select date, store, transaction from table where date=current_date)main_table
    left join
    (select date, store, transaction from table where date=date_sub(current_date,1))yest_table
    on date_sub(main_table.date,1)=yest_table.date and main_table.store=yest_table.store
    left join
    (select date, store, transaction from table where date=date_sub(current_date,7))lw_table
    on date_sub(main_table.date,7)=lw_table.date and main_table.store=yest_table.store
    left join
    (select date, store, transaction from table where date=date_sub(current_date,7))lm_table
    on add_months(current_date,-1)=lm_table.date and main_table.store=yest_table.store
```

is it correct? because i think there might be a better solution for this..

thank you

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: @TKHN sorry, i've updated my question

Comment: BTW In your subqueries (in joins) ON condition duplicates WHERE filter and in the lm_table subquery the filter is wrong, it should be `date=add_months(current_date,-1)`

Comment: @galih use partioning also for cols having high cardinality if not using

Answer (score 1):

Use `case` + `max()` aggregation:

```
select main.date,main.store,main.transaction,s.yesterday_trans,s.lastweek_trans,s.lastmonth_trans
    from
    (select date, store, transaction from table where date=current_date)main
    left join
    (select store, 
       max(case when date = date_sub(current_date,1)    then transaction end) yesterday_trans,  
       max(case when date = date_sub(current_date,7)    then transaction end) lastweek_trans,
       max(case when date = add_months(current_date,-1) then transaction end) lastmonth_trans
       from table 
      where date>=add_months(current_date,-1) and date<=date_sub(current_date,1)
      group by store
    ) s on main.store=s.store;
```

In such way you will eliminate two unnecessary table scans and joins.
This solution works only for current_date (or fixed parameter instead of current_date). If you want to select many dates from main table then the solution with three joins by dates + store will work best.

Well, probably, LAG is applicable solution as well...

```
select date,store,transaction,
    case when lag(date,1) over(partition by store order by date) = date_sub(date,1)) --check if LAG(1) is yesterday (previous date)
         then lag(transaction ,1) over(partition by store order by date) = date_sub(current_date,1)) 
    end as yesterday_trans 
...
--where date>=add_months(current_date,-1) and date<=date_sub(current_date,1)
```

Add aggregation if necessary. If solution with LAGs is applicable then it will be the fastest because does not require joins at all and does everything in a single scan. If you have many records per date, then probably you can pre-aggregate them before LAG. This will work not only for current_date

Comment: what if we dont have current_date..,means historical data..will have to pass the parameter..?

Comment: @TKHN Then only the original solution is applicable (three joins by dates).

Comment: yes..agree this a optimized option ..2 table scan would be heavy op